# I want group by pais_id and codigo fields

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select r.fecha_remesa,(select m.abreviatura from Moneda m where r.moneda_id=m.id),
case when r.tipo_doc=101 then 'CHK' else 'TRV' end as cheque,
r.importe,r.oficina,r.id,d.cod_fac,d.montante,r.entidad,d.pais_id,
case
when d.cod_fac=2 then 'I'
when d.cod_fac=1 then 'S'
else ''
end as prasa,
('9635CLR' || 
 to_char(er.fecha_procesado, 'YYMMDD') || 
 r.digito_remesa
) as codigo
from remesa r
left join documento d
on d.remesa_id = r.id
inner join envio_remesa er
on er.id = r.envio_remesa_id
where er.fecha_procesado >= TO_DATE('2021-09-07','YYYY-mm-DD') and er.fecha_procesado < TO_DATE('2021-09-07','YYYY-mm-DD') + 1
group by pais_id,codigo,r.fecha_remesa,r.importe,r.oficina,r.id,d.cod_fac,d.montante,r.entidad,d.pais_id,r.moneda_id ;
```

What i'm trying is to group by codigo and pais_id fields, i mean for example the 6th and 7th register are the same codigo and pais_id, so this should be one register. Actually it's not working. My query is throwing this:

[image]

Comment: You are not "group by codigo and pais_id fields", but you do a `group by pais_id,codigo,r.fecha_remesa,r.importe,r.oficina,r.id,d.cod_fac,d.montante,r.entidad,d.pais_id,r.moneda_id`, that is something different.... !

Comment: "Actually it's not working", please give more details about desired output, and share some  (input) data in TEXT, and not in an IMAGE.

Comment: Yeah..I mean i want groupying by codigo and pais_id fields.. but i can't get it. thats why i asked..

Comment: you are grouping by all the fields in the group by. If you want to group by only those two fields, you'll have to keep only those two fields in the `group by`and use aggregate functions (MIN, MAX, AVG, COUNT, etc)  for the other fields in the `select`

Comment: It is really unclear what you want/need. You say you want to group by 2 columns, but you do a group by 11 columns.  What should be outputted for a column like `r.fecha_remesa` which is currently in the group by ? There might be different values for that field in the current data.....

Comment: @NuLo could you put and example or answer the question? I don't understand you right now..

Comment: I probably can if you can tell me what the montante and the other columns that are not Pais and codigo should be for the line that would correspond to the 6th and 7th registers together